# Sort array using Mixed integer constraints

Tags: linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

Assume that I have
X = X_1....x_n Variables
and I want to build variables Y = Y_1...Y_n using constraints
such that the elements of Y are the sorted elements of X.

For example when

```
n = 2
Y_1 = min(X_1,X_2) 
Y_2 = max(X_1,X_2)
```

this can be achieved with BIG m notation and 1 binary variables(B).

```
Y_1 <= X_1
Y_1 <= X_2
Y_1 + B * M >= X_1
Y_1 + (1 - B) * M  >= X_2

Y_2 >= X_1
Y_2 >= X_2
Y_2 <= X_1 + (1 - B) * M
Y_2 <= X_2 + B * M
```

how can i build such a constraint for the general case? further, how can I do it with a minimum amount of binary variables?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your approach can not be generalized.

Let's assume `x[i] ∈ [L[i],U[i]]`.

First we introduce some assignment variables:

```
 sum(j, p[i,j]) = 1 ∀i
 sum(i, p[i,j]) = 1 ∀j
 p[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

Now we can do

```
 y[i] = sum(j, p[i,j]*x[j])
 y[i+1] >= y[i]
```

but this is nonlinear. So we do instead:

Linearization of `q[i,j] = p[i,j]*x[j]`:

```
  L[j]*p[i,j] <= q[i,j] <= U[j]*p[i,j]                     ∀i,j
  x[j]-U[j]*(1-p[i,j]) <= q[i,j] <= x[j]-L[j]*(1-p[i,j])   ∀i,j
  q[i,j] free
```

Calculate y:

```
  y[i] = sum(j, q[i,j])    ∀i
  y[i+1] >= y[i]           ∀i but the last
  y[i] free
```

This is just one approach. There are other formulations none of them really much simpler than this. This approach needs n^2 binary variables.

A small test case:

```
----     74 VARIABLE x.L  

i1   -72.953,    i2    26.640,    i3    -7.413,    i4   -41.832,    i5   -40.446,    i6   -60.748,    i7   -37.622
i8    35.341,    i9   -86.124,    i10   -1.560,    i11   60.284,    i12   -9.823,    i13   58.321,    i14   23.703
i15  -73.684,    i16   19.667,    i17  -71.349,    i18  -55.050,    i19    2.203,    i20  -24.663,    i21  -43.503
i22  -37.687,    i23  -72.174,    i24  -72.681,    i25   -8.824,    i26   39.548,    i27  -52.591,    i28    0.987
i29   35.956,    i30  -30.807,    i31  -68.515,    i32   -9.459,    i33  -66.911,    i34   45.721,    i35  -43.236
i36  -44.463,    i37   -6.925,    i38   24.830,    i39    7.334,    i40  -27.320,    i41  -13.336,    i42  -76.643
i43  -35.977,    i44  -73.598,    i45  -25.906,    i46  -67.654,    i47    4.287,    i48  -10.957,    i49   21.653
i50  -39.167,    i51   17.540,    i52   15.509,    i53   -2.124,    i54  -46.566,    i55  -82.363,    i56  -67.305
i57   15.262,    i58  -14.333,    i59  -85.537,    i60   36.240,    i61  -67.940,    i62  -58.333,    i63    3.244
i64   13.203,    i65  -68.595,    i66  -92.701,    i67    1.280,    i68   -3.644,    i69  -23.246,    i70  -43.362
i71  -51.336,    i72  -43.147,    i73  -68.123,    i74   53.356,    i75  -42.744,    i76   31.107,    i77  -43.717
i78  -56.794,    i79   16.927,    i80  -85.527,    i81  -69.082,    i82  -94.795,    i83  -58.025,    i84  -24.606
i85  -56.416,    i86  -58.833,    i87  -49.729,    i88  -47.562,    i89  -27.919,    i90   52.985,    i91   63.897
i92  -38.035,    i93  -28.051,    i94   19.678,    i95  -28.997,    i96   46.798,    i97  -61.927,    i98   23.847
i99  -81.919,    i100   0.390


----     74 VARIABLE y.L  

i1   -94.795,    i2   -92.701,    i3   -86.124,    i4   -85.537,    i5   -85.527,    i6   -82.363,    i7   -81.919
i8   -76.643,    i9   -73.684,    i10  -73.598,    i11  -72.953,    i12  -72.681,    i13  -72.174,    i14  -71.349
i15  -69.082,    i16  -68.595,    i17  -68.515,    i18  -68.123,    i19  -67.940,    i20  -67.654,    i21  -67.305
i22  -66.911,    i23  -61.927,    i24  -60.748,    i25  -58.833,    i26  -58.333,    i27  -58.025,    i28  -56.794
i29  -56.416,    i30  -55.050,    i31  -52.591,    i32  -51.336,    i33  -49.729,    i34  -47.562,    i35  -46.566
i36  -44.463,    i37  -43.717,    i38  -43.503,    i39  -43.362,    i40  -43.236,    i41  -43.147,    i42  -42.744
i43  -41.832,    i44  -40.446,    i45  -39.167,    i46  -38.035,    i47  -37.687,    i48  -37.622,    i49  -35.977
i50  -30.807,    i51  -28.997,    i52  -28.051,    i53  -27.919,    i54  -27.320,    i55  -25.906,    i56  -24.663
i57  -24.606,    i58  -23.246,    i59  -14.333,    i60  -13.336,    i61  -10.957,    i62   -9.823,    i63   -9.459
i64   -8.824,    i65   -7.413,    i66   -6.925,    i67   -3.644,    i68   -2.124,    i69   -1.560,    i70    0.390
i71    0.987,    i72    1.280,    i73    2.203,    i74    3.244,    i75    4.287,    i76    7.334,    i77   13.203
i78   15.262,    i79   15.509,    i80   16.927,    i81   17.540,    i82   19.667,    i83   19.678,    i84   21.653
i85   23.703,    i86   23.847,    i87   24.830,    i88   26.640,    i89   31.107,    i90   35.341,    i91   35.956
i92   36.240,    i93   39.548,    i94   45.721,    i95   46.798,    i96   52.985,    i97   53.356,    i98   58.321
i99   60.284,    i100  63.897
```

Comment: Can it be done with n log n binary variables?

Comment: Never seen that. Can you show how that should be done?

Comment: I can show you for n= 2,3,4, that i use relatively small amount of binary variable

Comment: I'd suggest implementing it for n variables. That is the real test.